# Is it possible to have a varying type parameter in a nested structure in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

One simple example corresponding to this question "a simple generically typed and type-safe LinkedList like Data Structure" where each next Node can be of different type. For example, the intention is to achieve this:

```
     interface LinkedNode<T1> {
        value: T1;
        next: LinkedNode<T2> | null; // Typescript gives error for T2 here.
      }

Use case:
      interface IPair{
        a:boolean;
        b: number;
      }
      let LinkedNode1: LinkedNode<string> = {value: "string1", next: null};
      let LinkedNode2: LinkedNode<number> = {value: 10, next: LinkedNode1};
      let LinkedNode3: LinkedNode<IPair> = {value: {a:true, b: 2}, next: LinkedNode2};
      let root: LinkedNode<boolean> = {value: true, next: LinkedNode3};

      let x = root.next.value.a; // ultimately this is the desired effect: to be able to get access to other linked node's member variables without having to manually typecast.
```

So, the question is: "For the `LinkedNode<T1>` interface above, replacing `<T2>` by `<any>` compiles, but looses type info. Is it possible to achieve the desired effect above without using `<any>` in place of `<T2>`? If not what is the alternative?"

Comment: This will be confusing conside first node is number and next one is string and next is date, on first item node is number and next is string, when you do next one current is string and next is Date, then all of that generic types is use less

However in your case you need to define `LinedNode<T1,T2>` to solve typescript error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you really want a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) of types where each element in the tuple descends one level down into your tree.  Or at least that's the only thing that makes sense to me, because you have to define your type of the root node in terms of the types of all the descendants.

Given a few [tuple-related features added in TypeScript 3.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), you can do the following:

```
// get the first element of a tuple; Head<[1,2,3]> is 1
type Head<L extends any[]> = 
  ((...l: L) => void) extends ((h: infer H, ...t: infer T) => void) ? H : never;

// get the tuple with the first element removed; Tail<[1,2,3]> is [2,3]
type Tail<L extends any[]> = 
  ((...l: L) => void) extends ((h: infer H, ...t: infer T) => void) ? T : never;

// represent LinkedNode in the following nested way
interface LinkedNode<T extends any[]> {
  value: Head<T>;
  next: LinkedNode<Tail<T>> | null; 
}
```

There's some funny business when you reach the end of your tuple, (`LinkedNode<[]>` and `LinkedNode<never>` are interesting types) but the `| null` hides it well enough.

Let's try it:

```
const node: LinkedNode<[string, number, boolean]> = {
  value: "a",
  next: {
    value: 1,
    next: {
      value: true,
      next: null
    }
  }
};

let LinkedNode1: LinkedNode<[string]> = { value: "string1", next: null };
let LinkedNode2: LinkedNode<[number, string]> = { value: 10, next: LinkedNode1 };
let LinkedNode3: LinkedNode<[IPair, number, string]> = { value: { a: true, b: 2 }, next: LinkedNode2 };
let root: LinkedNode<[boolean, IPair, number, string]> = { value: true, next: LinkedNode3 };
```

Looks good to me.

---

Before TS3.0 you could get something with nested generics, which is possibly more straightforward:

```
interface LinkedNode<T, N extends null | LinkedNode<any, any>=null> {
  value: T;
  next: N;
}

const node: LinkedNode<string, LinkedNode<number, LinkedNode<boolean>>> = {
  value: "a",
    next: {
    value: 1,
      next: {
      value: true,
        next: null
    }
  }
};

let LinkedNode1: LinkedNode<string> = {value: "string1", next: null};
let LinkedNode2: LinkedNode<number, typeof LinkedNode1> = {value: 10, next: LinkedNode1};
let LinkedNode3: LinkedNode<IPair, typeof LinkedNode2> = {value: {a:true, b: 2}, next: LinkedNode2};
let root: LinkedNode<boolean, typeof LinkedNode3> = {value: true, next: LinkedNode3};
```

Also looks good.  Does one of those help?

Comment: It certainly adds another perspective to the list of alternatives, but the problem I encountered is that once this type of structure is passesd to methods/functions which are dynamically created and destroyed by factory functions, it is necessary to use higher and higher level of type abstractions eg. using inheritance. Then, is it possible to store the "Type" of the "next" member itself in another member variable like this: 

interface INode<T> {value: T, nextNodeType: type of T2, next: INode<any>} ? 

But, I believe it might not be possible as that would probably require type-reflection.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand... if you have a concrete use case and an accompanying [mcve], someone might be able to answer.

Comment: Well, it's possible to do what I wanted to do in pure Javascript or just by replacing corresponding types by `any` in Typescript. I tried with the Variadic Generic typing with rest parameters and spread operators which kind of worked independently. However, passing these around as parameters to higher level factory functions over-complicated the code and needed manual casting again in some places. I gave up on my original structure/implementation, because what I wanted to achieve doesn't seem to be possible in a succint way.

Comment: For a simple example, we can  introduce a new type parameter `<T>` for a `method` inside a `class`. However, we can't do that for a `data member` of the class. I know it sounds weird (or even might seem to defeat the purpose of typing), but until I encountered one! 
`class A {
  f1 <T1> (p: T1){
    return p;
  }
/* data member  d1 is some type of a complex data type */
d1<T2>: T2; /* this is not possible */
}
`
Anyways, I believe the response above does answer the question in some extent with current language features, so, I have marked it as the answer.